# Can the norm of a vector be $\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading Pugh's Analysis and he defines a norm as a certain type of function from $V \to \mathbb{R}$. However, if we have two normed vector spaces, he later says that we can define the **operator norm** of a linear transformation by

$$||T|| = \sup \left \{\dfrac {|T(v)|}{|v|}: v \not = 0 \right \}$$

However, from what he says later in the text, I infer that there are some linear transformations whose norm is $\infty$. Thus my question is: is a norm actually a function to the extended reals, or is the operator norm not actually a norm, but a different type of object?

Comment: "However, from what he says later in the text, I infer that there are some linear transformations whose norm is $\infty$."  Please include a citation to that effect, because you may have "inferred" incorrectly.  Not all of us have Pugh's *Analysis* immediately at our disposal.

Comment: @amWhy There is a theorem which says "The following are equivalent: a) $||T||< \infty$, b)$T$ is continuous". I assume that there must be some discontinuous transformations, since otherwise there probably would've been a theorem before this which said  "all linear transformations are continous"

Comment: Be careful! The norm of an operator is not a norm of an element of a vector space, thus a norm of a vector. Look at the definition given.

Comment: You can think like this: we introduce a *function* $\|T\|$. For some $T$ it is finite, for other infinite. The space of all $T$ with finite $\|T\|$ can be made a normed vector space, where the function above works as a norm.

Comment: @Rebellos I was thinking of the function as a vector in the vector space of of all linear transformations.

Comment: @A.Γ. That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of a vector cannot be $\infty$ since a norm must be a function into $\mathbb{R}.$ Thus, in the set
$$ \text{End}(V) = \{ T:V\to\mathbb{R} \text{ | } T \text{ is a linear map}\}$$
the function $T\mapsto \| T\|$ does not (in general) define a norm. You should restrict $\| \thinspace\|$ to the subspace
$$ B(V)=\{ T:V\to\mathbb{R} \text{ | } T \text{ is a linear map and }\|T\|<\infty\}$$
to obtain a well defined norm $\|\thinspace\|:B(V)\to \mathbb{R},$ $T\mapsto \| T\|.$

Answer (score 1):

Calling $\|\cdot\|$ a norm is a small abuse of terminology. Norms must be finite by definition. However, any function satisfying all the norm axioms except for finiteness becomes a norm when restricted to the domain for which it is finite. Even though $\|\cdot\|$ can be infinite, it is a norm on the space of *continuous* linear operators.

For an example of a linear operator with infinite norm, consider the space of real sequences which are eventually zero with the sup norm, and the operator which takes such a sequence and multiplies its $n$th entry by $n.$